# issue with tkinter messagebox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I'm using several tkinter messageboxes in my code. But ive noticed a problem with the `showinfo` messageboxes I've used in my code. Basically, I want a function to be called when the `ok` on the messagebox is pressed. Also, the user can choose not to proceed by just closing the messagebox. But, it looks like when I press the x icon to close the messagebox, the function is still called. Here is a minimum reproducible code to explain what i mean.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def func() :
    Label(root,text="This is the text").pack()

msg = messagebox.showinfo("Loaded","Your saved state has been loaded")
if msg == "ok" :
    func()

root.mainloop()
```

My question is, **What should i do so that the function is not called when the x icon is pressed?**

Comment: No answer for it, but can build a user popup window for special requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of `messagebox`, the one your using here is not what you actually should be using for your case. What you want is something called `askyesno`, or something that is prefixed by 'ask' because your code depend upon the users action. So you want to 'ask' the user, like:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()

def func() :
    Label(root,text="This is the text").pack(oadx=10,pady=10)

msg = messagebox.askyesno("Loaded","Your saved state has been loaded")
if msg: #same as if msg == True:
    func()

root.mainloop()
```

Here, `askyesno` like other 'ask' prefixed functions will return `True` or `1` if you click on the 'Yes' button, else it will return `False` or `0`.

Also just something I realized now, `showinfo`, like other 'show' prefixed messagebox function, returns `'ok'` either you press the button or close the window.

Some more 'ask' prefixed messageboxes ~ `askokcancel`, `askquestion`, `askretrycancel`, `askyesnocancel`. Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.messagebox.html)

Comment: Thaks this was just what i needed. But just out of curiosity, is there any way to make the x icon on the ```showinfo``` messagebox just close the window??

Comment: @Jovan Well, these `messagebox` have limited functionality. If you want such a feature, you will have to make your own `messagebox`.